# How do I remove elements that do not directly contain text themselves - Python BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nlp

**Problem summary:** I want to preprocess HTML documents for NLP tasks, and one step of preprocessing is to remove elements/tags that do not contain text directly. I've tried my best to find an approach that works, but even the simple version of the <kbd>remove_tags_without_text()</kbd> function doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this?

**Test input:**

```py
"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      <p>
        <p>this should be here
          <br/>this should be here
        </p>
      </p>
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
"""
```

**Expected output:**

```py
"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>this should be here
      <br/>this should be here
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
"""
```

**Code:**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def remove_tags_without_text(text:str) -> str:
  locked = ["html", "body", "ul", "br"]
  soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
  #Remove tags with no text
  for tag in soup.find_all():
    if tag.name in locked:
      continue
    children = tag.findChildren(recursive=False)
    if len(children) < 1:
      continue
    first_child = children[0]
    if tag.text is None:
      tag.replaceWith(first_child)
    children = children[1:]
    last_child = first_child
    for child in children:
      current_child = child
      last_child.insert_after(current_child)
      last_child = current_child
  return soup.prettify()

def main():
  test = """
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <p>
        <p>
          <p>this should be here
            <br/>this should be here
          </p>
        </p>
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
  """
  result = remove_tags_without_text(test)
  print(result)
  return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `smooth()` with standard parser `lxml` and checking the length of the text in your tags, if it is equal to 0 `decompose()` the tag:

```
soup.smooth()
locked = ['html', 'body', 'ul', 'li']
for t in soup.find_all():
    if len(t.get_text(strip=True)) == 0 and t.name not in locked:
        t.decompose()
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      <p>
        <p>this should be here
          <br/>this should be here
        </p>
      </p>
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.smooth()
locked = ['html', 'body', 'ul', 'li']
for t in soup.find_all():
    if len(t.get_text(strip=True)) == 0 and t.name not in locked:
        t.decompose()

soup
```

###### Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>this should be here
          this should be here
        </p>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```